# why am I getting buffer is not a function error

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm a noobie with observables and I'm trying to create an observable clickstream to ignore the 2 click events that occur when double-clicking, but I'm getting this error:-

`Unhandled Promise rejection: this.clickStream.buffer is not a function ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: TypeError: this.clickStream.buffer is not a function`

and I don't understand why.

The code is as follows:-

```
import {Component, NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {Subject} from 'rxjs/Subject';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
         <div>
              <button (click)="clickStream.next(1)">Click me!</button>
         </div>
    `,
})
export class App {
    clickStream: Observable<number> = new Subject<number>();
    singleClick;

    constructor() {
        this.singleClick = this.clickStream.buffer(() => this.clickStream
                                                             .debounce(250))
                               .map(arr => arr.length)
                               .filter(len => len != 2);
        this.singleClick.subscribe(console.log.bind(console));
    }
}

@NgModule({
     imports: [ BrowserModule ],
     declarations: [ App ],
     bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

I've been using the `Angular + Typescript Demo Plunk` to test this.

Comment: import 'rxjs/add/operator/buffer'; ?

Comment: That got rid of the errors by importing all the operators, but nothing happens when I press the button. I had similar code working fine in `codepen.io` and I'm trying to get this working as `angular/typescript` code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is this line

```
this.singleClick = this.clickStream.buffer(() => this.clickStream.debounce(250))
```

The `bufferWhen` operator uses a function, but `buffer` just uses the observable:

```
this.singleClick = this.clickStream.buffer(this.clickStream.debounce(250))
```

[LEARN RXJS - buffer](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/buffer.html)

I'm wondering if you even need the buffer, debounce should be sufficient.

Also, there's `debounce` which takes a function and `debounceTime` which takes the ms time - so you want to change that as well.

I've set up a [CodePen](https://codepen.io/RMatsen/pen/YEzLbw) to play with.

Comment: When I use `this.singleClick = this.clickStream.buffer(this.clickStream.debounce(250))` I get `ERROR TypeError: this.durationSelector.call is not a function`.

Comment: That message would be coming from the debounce error.

Comment: Woohoo! Check out the CodePen as well, simple `debounceTime` might give you the result you want.